# how to parallelize the sending of data to the database

Tags: r, rmysql

I have a large csv file. I read the file every 10000 lines then send these lines to a database, it takes a lot of time. What I would like to test is to parallelize. I implemented this code but nothing happens, there are no errors.

```
library(parallel); library(doParallel); library(RMySQL);  

con <- dbConnect(MySQL(), host = host, user = user, password = password, dbname = database)

path <- "file.csv"
col_names <- colnames(read.csv(path, header = T, nrows = 1))
offsets <- seq(0, file.info(path)$size / 2, by = batch_size) # length(offsets) = 335363
batch_size <- 10000

cl <- makeCluster(detectCores())
registerDoParallel(cl)
foreach(i = 1:length(offsets), .packages = c("DBI")) %dopar% {
  header <- if(i > 1) F else T
  setb <- read.csv(path, skip = offsets[i], nrows = batch_size, 
                   header = header)
  colnames(setb) <- col_names
  dbWriteTable(con, "table1", setb, append = TRUE)
}

stopCluster(cl); dbDisconnect(con)
```

Comment: I'm skeptical that you can append in parallel. Anyway, you would need to open a database connection for each worker (ie., inside the loop). However, I don't understand why you are even doing this. Why don't you just `COPY` the whole CSV into the database? Why do you need to involve R?

Comment: I don't think the connection object (con) is  designed to be used in parallel.

Comment: @Roland Hello, I use phpmyadmin. It indicates that the maximum size accepted is 500MiB. I still tried to import and I have no indication of the progress or the fact that it is working but maybe I have to be patient.  I waited already 30min.

Comment: how large is the csv?

Comment: Won't it slow down the query especially if there are indices that need to be updated? I would consider uploading the data at once after locking the table and suppressing index update until the upload finishes

Comment: @Mark, the file is 8GB but I have an old computer from 2009, 2010 when I open the file with excel or R the computer freezes.

Comment: Generally the approach is to read data line by line, buffer it in reasonable sizes and send those chunks to the db, sequentially. This way even very large amounts of data can be stored in mere seconds, even on "old" computers. It doesn't need a lot of cpu power (which parallelization addresses), the bottleneck usually is the io, i.e hard drive and network speed.